# Virtual Box Drag and Drop with Windows10(guest) and Linux(host)

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running a Windows 10 instance in VirtualBox on my Kubuntu system. I want to exchange files per drag and drop from guest to host, but somehow it works only from host to guest. I have already installed the guest extensions on the Windows instance and drag and drop is activated bidirectional. Any ideas why it won't work?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you reboot both Host and Guest after installing Guest Extensions?

Comment: @John yes, I did reboot both systems

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling guest extensions on the guest machine